# Is the following equality about conditional probability holds always? P ( ( A ∩ B ) ∣ C ) = P ( A ∣ C ) ∗ P ( B ∣ ( C ∩ A ) ) .

Tags: probability

I encounter with the following equality in a question, but I don't know these are equivalent or is it found like below just because of the design of the question. Is the following a general rule?

$$ P((A\cap B)∣ C)=P(A∣ C)*P(B∣ (C\cap A))$$

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are not familiar with [conditional probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability#Conditioning_on_an_event) because otherwise the question you have asked is just arithmetic.
$$LHS = \frac{P(A\cap B\cap C)}{P(C)}$$
$$RHS = \frac{P(A\cap C)}{P(C)} \times \frac{P(B\cap C \cap A)}{P(C\cap A)}$$

Use the fact that intersection is a commutative operator to conclude that $LHS=RHS$